A type of differentiation under the integral sign
This question arises in a problem I'm working on in climate economics. Let $X\left( s \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahCart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% iwamaabmaabaGaam4CaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!3B70!
$
be a real variable. How does one differentiate $\int\limits_0^t {X\left( s \right) ds} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahCart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaa8
% qCaeaacaWGybWaaeWaaeaacaWGZbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaacciGae8hi
% aaIaamizaiaadohaaSqaaiaaicdaaeaacaWG0baaniabgUIiYdaaaa!423E!
$
with respect to $X\left( t \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahCart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% iwamaabmaabaGaamiDaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!3B71!
$
, the value of $X\left(  \bullet  \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahCart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% iwamaabmaabaGaeyOiGClacaGLOaGaayzkaaaaaa!3BFD!
$
at the upper limit?
I posed this to ChatGPT and it used the Dirac delta function to conclude that the answer is 1. However, I've found it sometimes makes math mistakes, and in any case I didn't understand its logic.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Functional derivative: $\displaystyle{\delta\operatorname{X}\left(s\right) \over  \delta\operatorname{X}\left(t\right)} = \delta\left(s - t\right)$

Dimensional analysis shows the answer needs the units of $t$, so ChatGPT is wrong.

Thank you all for your responses. Felix Marin, could you elaborate on how I use this functional derivative to calculate the answer?

Do not use chatGPT for anything other than amusement. It only strings together words based on a probabilistic model, it is not a search engine, it does not do any computation. It doesn't "sometimes make math mistakes". It sometimes just happens to say the right thing, much like a broken clock is right twice a day.

J. G.: If the integral happens to be linear in the terminal value of X(.), then the derivative is a constant. Could you explain the dimensional analysis you're referring to?

From this question we can just use the chain rule in a certain way. Let $$f(t) = \int_0 ^t X(s) \ ds.$$ Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dX(t)} &= \frac{df/dt}{dX(t)/dt} \\
&= \frac{X(t)}{X'(t)} \\
\end{align*}
assuming, of course, $X$ is differentiable.

Sean Roberson: In their Mar. 18, 2021 response to the question you linked, user49404 provides a formal derivation of the chain-rule cancellation heuristic. If one applies that to my problem, one step is taking the partial of the integral with respect to the function X(.) - i.e., the function itself, not the terminal value. How does one do that? Thanks.

You may need to look at Steiltjes integrals, where you can integrate with respect to a function (of bounded variation).
